# C++: Can an unused lambda explicit capture be optimized out?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, language-lawyer

I have a decent amount of code that relies on capturing a `shared_from_this()` when using a lambda expression as a callback to ensure that my instance stays alive:

```
std::shared_ptr<Thing> self = shared_from_this();
auto doSomething = [this, self] ()
{
    // various statements, none of which reference self, but do use this
}
```

So the question is: Since I am not referencing `self` inside the lambda body, is a conformant compiler allowed to optimize the capture away?

---

Consider the following program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

std::function<void ()> gFunc;

struct S : std::enable_shared_from_this<S>
{
    void putGlobal()
    {
        auto self = shared_from_this();
        gFunc = [self] { };
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared<S>();
    std::cout << x.use_count() << std::endl;
    x->putGlobal();
    std::cout << x.use_count() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
```

This indicates that `g++-4.7.1` does not optimize the capture away (nor does `clang-3.1`).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The standard guarantees that captured values are not optimized away (per §5.1.2/14):

> **An entity is captured by copy if** it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if **it is explicitly
>   captured** with a capture that does not include an &. **For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-
>   static data member is declared in the closure type.** The declaration order of these members is unspecified.
>   The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a
>   reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise.

So, `self` is copied into the closure on evaluation (per §5.1.2/21):

> When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize
>   each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object.

Comment: This seems to contradict [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181464/c11-lambda-capture-semantics), which says if it's ODR unused then it's not actually captured.

Comment: @GManNickG: The difference is that of implicit capturing (`[=]`) and *explicit* capturing (`[someNameHere]`). Implicit capturing requires ODR used elements. Explicit capturing does not.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Gotcha. An entity is implicitly captured if and only if it's ODR used. At that point, it's in the same boat as explicitly captured entities. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW expr.prim.lambda.closure/2 says this: An implementation may define the closure type differently from what is described below provided this does not alter the observable behavior
of the program other than by changing the size and/or alignment [..]

Not sure whether this allows eliding the capture-by-copy but I suppose not, as copy-initialization of the captured variable has observable side effect to the abstract machine.