# If I capture by value and don't use it will I still get a copy?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I wan't to capture a shared_ptr by value in a lambda to ensure the lifetime of the object extends to the point the lambda function is called.

I don't actually need the shared_ptr otherwise. If I do:

```
shared_ptr<..> sp;
sp->async_call( [sp](){} );
```

Is sp guaranteed to get copied even though the body doesn't reference it?

Comment: Seems like the same question as [C++: Can an unused lambda explicit capture be optimized out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718423/c-can-an-unused-lambda-explicit-capture-be-optimized-out)

Comment: @c45207 yeah looks like he basically deduced the same thing as me

Comment: As a general rule you can answer almost any "can X be optimised?" question about C++ with another question: "can the program tell the difference?"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes true most of the time but sometimes c++ is allowed to optimize out cctors with side effects, like in return values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that it is guaranteed because of this quote.
5.1.2

> 21 When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy **are used to direct-initialize each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object**. (For array members, the array elements are direct-initialized in increasing subscript order.) These initializations are performed in the (unspecified) order in which the non-static data members are declared. [Note: This ensures that the destructions will occur in the reverse order of the constructions. — end note ]

EDIT: On second thought since the object is direct-initialized copy elision doesn't even come into play.
<strike>Because of the criteria for copy elision in `§ 12.8`, too long to post, I don't believe that the copy can be elided</strike>

Something to keep in mind though, `std::shared_ptr` is not thread safe for most purposes.

Comment: the "as if" rule is a big question mark in this case in my opinion, personally I wouldn't expect to find the `ptr` inside the lambda because the state of this `ptr` is not even loaded/accessed or altered.

Comment: Seems a bit like asking if std::lock_guard can be optimised away, since it's not referenced.  Of course, it can't because the effects of the constructor and destructor are observable.  For this reason I think that the captured entity must have its destructor executed at the end of the lambdas scope, even if the copy-constructor could be optimised away.

Comment: @BenPope there are some cases where the copy constructor(and thus the destructor ) can be optimized away even if there are side effects

Comment: @aaronman Copy elision can ignore side effects, but not in such a way as to interfere with RAII; When copy elision occurs the original object's lifetime is simply extended to the longer of the two lifetimes, thus ensuring that the original object's resources are correctly handled.

Comment: And copy elision only has permission to break the as-if rule when turning two objects into a single object; it can't break the as-if rule in order to turn a single object into zero objects.

Comment: @bames53 id have to reread the rules but i just wanted to point out a case where it could happen