# Forcing C++11 lambda to capture a variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

Suppose copying a variable has a needed side effect. And I want to declare a lambda that copies the variable but doesn't otherwise use the variable. What's the minimum required to do this?

```
Copiable copyable;

auto lambda1 = [=](){};
auto lambda2 = [copyable](){};
auto lambda3 = [=](){ copyable; }
auto lambda4 = [=](){ volatile copy = copyable; }
```

`lambda1` uses implicit capture, and since the body doesn't mention `copyable`, I don't believe it actually copies it.

`lambda2` uses explicit capture, and it seems according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181464/do-c11-lambdas-capture-variables-they-dont-use), it should capture by copy. Is the compiler allowed to elide the copy? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718423/c-can-an-unused-lambda-explicit-capture-be-optimized-out) for another discussion of this.

`lambda3` uses implicit capture but the body mentions `copyable`. Does this constitute an *odr-use* of `copyable`?

`lambda4` uses implicit capture and forces another `volatile` copy. I'm sure this will actually work, but it's doing more copies than the minimum.

*Motivating case: I need to run a cleanup after an arbitrary number of lambda calls are completed, possibly in different threads. I can do this by using a `std::shared_ptr` with a custom deleter that runs the cleanup, and somehow passing this to each lambda. Then when all the shared ptrs go out of scope, the cleanup will run.*

*Edit: `lambda3` and `lambda4` were missing the `=` for implicit capture.*

Comment: Generally the compiler won't copy anything it doesn't have to.

Comment: You should never rely on a copy having side effects, because the compiler is allowed to elide copies. Why not just create a class that can perform the cleanup? Then have each lambda call an instance of that class at the end.

Comment: If you absolutely must rely on the copy side effects ( which I discourage you to ), you can also give your `copyable` as parameter that you never use to your lambda. However this entire thing seems like there are probably many much better ways to do what you intent to do, so please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) if you want help for alternatives.

Comment: @DDrmmr: Copy elision is only allowed in certain well-defined circumstances; you can rely on copies happening in other circumstances, including lambda capture. In any case, this isn't relying on side-effects of copying so much as the existence of the captured object for the lifetime of the lambda.

Comment: @DDrmmr I have a setup phase, where I arrange for several lambdas to be called from a different thread. The cleanup should happen after the set up is done and all the callbacks complete. This seems to indicate I need an atomic refcount. The atomic refcount must persist beyond the initial setup, all the way to the end of the callback completion. Thus likely it has to be a heap allocated var pointed to by a `shared_ptr`. At which stage I might as well use a `shared_ptr<void>` and use the deleter to clean up, avoid complicated atomic shared var handling.

Comment: @Glen Low Consider using a [barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers). You should also consider how you want to handle exceptions. Do you still want your cleanup to run when the initialization throws? Can the cleanup itself throw? Note that if you use a `shared_ptr`, you cannot throw (or leak) an exception from the deleter.

Comment: @DDrmmr Thanks for that, barrier looks good but I was trying to avoid boost if possible. It looks like it needs to be configured with a definite number of threads to rendezvous. However, it's only at the end of the setup phase that I will know how many threads to rendezvous, and it's also possible that some threads may rendezvous before the setup is done. Cleanup is essentially just a callback to notify the upper level done that all work is done, and passes back any errors rather than exceptions, like node.js/async type programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the minimum required to do this?

Explicit capture by value, as in `lambda2`.

> `lambda1` uses implicit capture, and since the body doesn't mention copyable, I don't believe it actually copies it.

That's right. Variables are only implicitly captured if they're *odr-used* within the lambda.

> `lambda2` uses explicit capture, and it seems according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181464/do-c11-lambdas-capture-variables-they-dont-use), it should capture by copy.

That's right. Any explicitly captured variables will be captured, whether they're used or not. This is what you want to do to ensure your object is captured.

> Is the compiler allowed to elide the copy? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718423/c-can-an-unused-lambda-explicit-capture-be-optimized-out) for another discussion of this.

No. If a variable is captured, then it's captured. The link doesn't really "discuss" that; the only answer confirms that this is the case, with the appropriate wording from the standard.

> `lambda3` uses implicit capture but the body mentions copyable. Does this constitute an *odr-use* of copyable?

Yes. The definition of *odr-use* is

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is *odr-used* unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied.

and the exception doesn't apply since it isn't constant (and therefore can't appear in a constant expression). (But note that this is ill-formed since there's no default capture.)

> `lambda4` uses implicit capture and forces another volatile copy. I'm sure this will actually work, but it's doing more copies than the minimum.

Indeed; you're forcing implicit capture by using the value, and forcing an extra copy. That's unnecessary, since `lambda2` does what you want.

Comment: That works for me (clang 3.4)! Only remaining irritation is that once I use explicit capture, I cannot then use implicit capture for the rest of the vars i.e. `auto lambda2 = [copyable, =](){};` doesn't compile.

Comment: @GlenLow: The default capture has to come before the capture list, `[=,copyable]`.

Comment: Note that `copyable` is odr-used in `lambda3`, since it is not a constant expression. But that's irrelevant, because `lambda3` doesn't capture anything. If it is a local lambda expression, it is ill-formed, otherwise `copyable` (inside `lambda3`) refers to the (global) variable `copyable` directly.

Comment: @MWid: You're right, I'd forgotten the definition of odr-use.

Comment: `[=,copyable]` is ill-formed. If the capture-default is `=` then each identifier in the lambda-capture must be preceded by `&`.

Comment: @MWid: What a weird restriction. In that case, I give up; the rules governing how to control capture are too rigid to sensibly capture otherwise unused variables. Unfortunately, the answer's been accepted so I can't delete it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, if you use the capture-default `=` then any (implicitly) captured entity is captured by copy. If you want an entity to be captured by reference then you have to state that explicitly by using `&`. But you cannot explicitly capture an entity by copy in this case.

Comment: @MikeSeymour worry not, the answer is good as is. I ended up having to explicitly capture every variable I needed, which is not a monumental pain since the scope is fairly tight and explicit capture serves as a good reminder that these vars need to exist after the lambda set up all the way to the eventual end of lambda execution.

Comment: @MikeSeymour you're right that the lambda3 and lambda4 expressions are missing the `=`. I'll edit it and you can fix your reply if you wish.